# Is there a way to rotate the Refresh Icon of UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh until refresh done?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibarbuttonitem

I'm setting up a UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh, and want to rotate the refresh icon of the UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh until refresh done. How can I achieve this?

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh)];

- (void)refresh {
    //start rotate the refresh icon animation
}

- (void)done {
    //stop rotate the refresh icon animation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't publicly access the icon of a UIBarButtonItem created with a system item.

You will need to create your own icon and image view then create the bar button item with `initWithCustomView:`. Then you can access the bar button item's `customView` property when needed and apply whatever animation you need to the image view.